# SQL error after Magento update

Tags: sql, magento

I'm getting the SQL error:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx` SELECT `i`.`entity_id`, `i`.`customer_group_id`, `i`.`website_id`, `o`.`option_id`, IF((@price:=IF(IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price_type, opd.price_type)='fixed', IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price, opd.price), ROUND(i.price * (IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price, opd.price) / 100), 4))) AND o.is_require, @price,0) AS `min_price`, @price AS `max_price`, IF(i.base_tier IS NOT NULL, IF((@tier_price:=IF(IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price_type, opd.price_type)='fixed', IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price, opd.price), ROUND(i.base_tier * (IF(ops.option_price_id>0, ops.price, opd.price) / 100), 4))) AND o.is_require, @tier_price, 0), NULL) AS `tier_price`, `i`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` AS `i`
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON cw.website_id = i.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = i.store_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option` AS `o` ON o.product_id = i.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `opd` ON opd.option_id = o.option_id AND opd.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_option_price` AS `ops` ON ops.option_id = opd.option_id AND ops.store_id = cs.store_id ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`)
```

It was working but after a Magento update to 1.8, it doesn't work anymore. Anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: From here you have got this error??

Comment: I'm trying to adapt plugin to magento 1.8

Comment: there are issue in your plugin.................